# Looping character around width of screen?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

What I am trying to do is lets say my character moves off the right side of the screen, I want it to come back around from the left part of the screen with the same Y coordinate. I am using Cocos2D also. I am currently trying to do this in my UIAccelerometer method but it does not seem to work.
Can someone show me what I should do instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change your character's position if it leaves the left or right side of the screen to the other side, without modifying the y coordinate.

```
CGSize size = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CGPoint pos = character.position;
if (pos.x >= size.width)
    pos.x -= size.width;
else if (pos.x < 0.0f)
    pos.x += size.width;
character.position = pos;
```

The reason why I add or subtract the width rather than setting the x coordinate directly to 0 or width is that the character may be moving faster than 1 pixel per frame. That means if he's moving fast and moves let's say from X coordinate 479 to 495 in one frame, then he should be set to X coordinate 15 on the other side to make sure the velocity of the character is unaffected.